# Beacon Hybrid Application MobileFirst 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, altbeacon, android-ibeacon, beacon

we are trying to crate a Mobile First Hybrid applicaiton which can detect beacons on basis of UUID.

Mobile First Native Application for Beacons already available in IBM sample applicaitons.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/working-with-beacons/beacons-in-android/

To achieve same in hybrid application we created one HTTP adapter which returned all registered beacons Information on Mobile First server
and we used android beacon library

https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

and configured in my Hybrid android project, Now My android application is able to detect beacons in region in specified Beacon region.

Now my problem is

Is above mentioned approch is correct or some one can tell me better approch?

"didEnterRegion" event occure again and again for same beacon, how can i manage with Enter and Exit Region of Beacon?

Is there any working sample application for Beacons Mobile first Hybrid application?

Answer (score 0):

It's impressive that you managed to get it to work in Hybrid applications.
That said, there is no official support for Beacons in Hybrid applications. As such there is also no sample application available.